# Laser printer faintly printing where it shouldn't be

Tags: print-design, print-production, digital-printing, paper, laser

[image]
I am not sure what to call this problem, but the laser printer (HP Color Laser Jet Pro) is doubling some of the print where it shouldn't be in a faint way. How could I fix this, or what is this problem called? Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Hardware questions are off topic here. Sorry about that. If you suspect a fault, contact the manufacturer instead.

Comment: Looks like something could be stuck on one of the rolls inside the printer. But yeah, off topic for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuser is bad.. needs replaced.. Fusers are **not** cheap. They are the heart of the printer.

Call a tech, you **can't** fix this yourself. Or take it to a repair shop for an estimate.

This often happens because someone is running printed sheets through the printer a second time when the printer is not designed for that. Toner/wax gets stuck to the fuser (which is the heater) and then transferred back to prints in the future.

Printing *a lot* of blank sheets may help diminish the problem a great deal, but it's not going to go away until the fuser is *replaced*.

Due to the price of some fusers, it can often be close to the same cost as just replacing the printer entirely. Last time I had a fuser go bad.. the printer originally cost me $250.... lasted a good 3-5 years, then the fuser replacement, with labor, was estimated to cost ~$280... I bought a new printer instead.

This is why user manuals tell you *not* to run prints through the machine twice.